# post_modified = post_date

Tags: date

Not work code, why?

```
function update_modified_date_to_post_date( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_modified = '{$post->post_date}', post_modified_gmt = '{$post->post_date_gmt}' WHERE ID = {$post->ID}" );
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'update_modified_date_to_post_date', 10, 1 );
```

Sorry for my English. Please help me.